# stable baslines3 runtime error: cannot infer dtype of numpy.float32

Tags: python, machine-learning, reinforcement-learning, stable-baselines

```
from stable_baselines3 import A2C
model=A2C('MlpPolicy',env,verbose=1)
model.learn(total_timesteps=10000)
```

I am using this on CartPole-v1

```
env=gym.make('CartPole-v1')
```

And I am getting

```
RuntimeError: Could not infer dtype of numpy.float32
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

it is problem with combability, so for start my recommendations update your pytorch
I solved this problem for python3.10 with the next version of pytorch

pip install torch===1.11.0 torchvision===0.1.6 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).